# Suggestion for how to analyse groups of data with 4 attributes

Tags: data-visualization, repeated-measures, data-mining

In my final project for Data Mining course, I chose to analyze IMDB movie data.

So far I have constructed a data set with all the movies until 2005. There are 24 movie genres and each genre has dozens to over a thousand movies in it with four attributes: rating at 2005, rating at 2015, # of votes at 2005, and # of votes at 2015.

My goal is to analyze if there's any interesting trend of how the movie genres' ratings or popularity change in ten years.

But since I'm new to the world of data mining, I know very little of the analyze methods. My professor suggested me to do a significance testing on some of the major genres (comedy, drama, action, horror, sci-fi, etc) and see if there are noticeable trends within those genres. But I'd like to get some more insights, such as what method I can use to graph my dataset in order to show the best results.

---

Edit: you don't have to tell me how to exactly carrying out the analysis, so the answer doesn't have to be long. I'm only asking for the suggestion on what method or theorem I should consider. I will figure out the literal steps of carrying out the analysis on my own.

My data consist of 24 movie genres, each containing 50-1500ish movie titles with 4 attributes: rating at 2005, rating at 2015, # of votes at 2005, and # of votes at 2015. And I'm trying to see if there's any interesting trend of movie genres' rating or popularity (of the same movies) change throughout ten years.

Comment: Hello I edited my question. Hopefully it will fit the rules this time!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, the first means to use is linear regression.
It could be easily done with Excel (see img.): make a scatterplot of e.g. 2015 votes (y-axis) vs 2005 votes (x-axis) for each film in the genre. Then, insert linear trend line, display $R^2$ value and regression equation (see example img below).

[image: Linear regression]

The rating could be treated the same way.

Also we can test the null hypothesis H<sub>0</sub> [that the true correlation coefficient ρ is equal to 0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient#Testing_using_Student.27s_t-distribution):

$r_{crit}={\frac {t}{\sqrt {n-2+t^{2}}}}.$

n - number of degreees of freedom,

t - critical value of two-sided t-distribution (e.g. for $\alpha$ = 0.05 significance level)

If our sample correlation coefficient value $r$ (that is equal to $\sqrt{R^2}$ for the simple linear regression) is less than critical value $r_{crit}$, one may say that under prescribed significance level there is no difference between correlation coefficient and 0, thus, there is no correlation.

In the example above, there is a positive correlation between 2005 and 2015 votes, so we could say this genre seems to become more popular in the recent years.

Comment: It's hard to imagine that scores for the same movies at two points in time would be totally uncorrelated.  I suspect there is a more meaningful analysis possible.

Comment: We could access the correlation strength (maybe, a bit subjective?): generally, |r|>0.8 means high correlation, 0.4<|r|<0.8 means medium correlation. I also would like to know answers from professional/semiprofessional statisticians! It is my (maybe, bad :( ) suggestion.